# AJAX update panel not working with Bootstrap 3

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I simply create a `TextBox`  in a Web Form and set its property such as `AutoPostBack=true` and write a one function on its `TextChanged` Event in a code behind files

Here Is code For my `TextBox`

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                     <label>Basic Salary : </label>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txt_basic_salary" runat="server" CssClass='form-control addition' 
                         placeholder="Basic Salary" TabIndex="4" AutoPostBack="True" 
                         ontextchanged="txt_basic_salary_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>                    
                </div> 
                </ContentTemplate>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Here a code for my `TextChanged` Event in a code behind file

```
protected void txt_basic_salary_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e){
   // do something 
}
```

Please suggest the corrections with my above code thanks in advance for your answers

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding trigger?

```
      <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">

    <ContentTemplate>

    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                         <label>Basic Salary : </label>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txt_basic_salary" runat="server" CssClass='form-control addition' 
                             placeholder="Basic Salary" TabIndex="4" AutoPostBack="True" 
                             ontextchanged="txt_basic_salary_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox> 
</div>
                </ContentTemplate>
            <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="txt_basic_salary" EventName="textchanged" />
            </Triggers>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
```